# jQuery fadeIn leaves text not anti-aliased in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Why does this happen? Any workarounds?

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
   $('p.quote').fadeIn(3000);
});
```

HTML:

```
<p>someone said:</p>
<p class="quote">&ldquo;lorem ipsum&rdquo;</p>
<p>someone else said:</p>
<p class="quote" style="display: none;">&ldquo;magna carta&rdquo;</p>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a known bug with IE and the fadeIn/fadeOut functions and their effect on text elements. Check out the info here:

<strike>http://blog.bmn.name/2008/03/jquery-fadeinfadeout-ie-cleartype-glitch/</strike>

Looks like my original link has since gone dead. Updated with a different solution from the comments:

http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/cleartype.html

The workaround is to remove the 'filter' property of the element in a callback function after fadeIn() has finished.

Comment: Well, it's not pretty in that it fades in the aliased text then snaps the filter off, but it works. We need to fade the filter too! Dam IE.

Comment: StackOverflow suffers from this very problem (when you click "load new answers"). I hope one of the team sees this answer.

Answer (score 17):

I found a better, more general solution, at http://jquery.malsup.com/fadetest.html.

I've taken that and adapted it into a standalone JavaScript file to be included in pages that use the jQuery fade*() methods.

```
//
//  jQuery IE Fade Fix
//
//  Adapted from code found at http://jquery.malsup.com/fadetest.html.
//
//  This is only needed for IE 7 and earlier, so this is best added to your page using IE's conditional comments
//  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx) as follows:
//      <!--[if lt IE 8]><script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ie-fade-fix.js"></script><![endif]-->
//
(function($) {
    $.fn.fadeIn = function(speed, callback) {
        if ($.isFunction(speed) && callback == undefined) {
            callback = speed;
            speed = 'normal';
        }
        return this.animate({opacity: 'show'}, speed, function() {
            if ( $.browser.msie )
            {
                this.style.removeAttribute('filter');
            }
            if ( $.isFunction(callback) )
            {
                callback.call(this);
            }
        });
    };

    $.fn.fadeOut = function(speed, callback) {
        if ($.isFunction(speed) && callback == undefined) {
            callback = speed;
            speed = 'normal';
        }
        return this.animate({opacity: 'hide'}, speed, function() {
            if ( $.browser.msie )
            {
                this.style.removeAttribute('filter');
            }
            if ( $.isFunction(callback) )
            {
                callback.call(this);
            }
        });
    };

    $.fn.fadeTo = function(speed, to, callback) {
        if ($.isFunction(speed) && callback == undefined) {
            callback = speed;
            speed = 'normal';
        }
        return this.animate({opacity: to}, speed, function() {
            if ( to == 1 && $.browser.msie )
            {
                this.style.removeAttribute('filter');
            }
            if ( $.isFunction(callback) )
                {
                callback.call(this);
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

**EDIT:** Incorporated [joeformd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54221/joeformd)'s fix for the callbacks.

**EDIT2:** Added fix for corner case where speed is not defined but callback is -Tomi

Comment: That's a great drop-in solution but the callbacks didnt work for me (broke the 'this' scope I think) I've posted a modified version here:

http://www.joelanman.com/archives/15

Comment: Thanks @joeformd. I've incorporated your fix into the sample code.

Comment: Upvoted this answer. I much prefer this simple drop-in solution. Thanks for sharing. Worked great for me.

Answer (score 5):

From what I remember, the filter attribute being set causes this. After your fadeIn is complete, remove the filter attribute from the element.

```
$('p.quote').fadeIn(2000, removeFilter);

function removeFilter() {
  $('p.quote').removeAttr("filter");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply apply background color to exact element you fading.. as far as I remember it won't work on children's if if you apply to parent, so it has to be on this very element that gets aliased.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the accepted answer now has a dead link. I think the same information is now available at http://blog.wolffmyren.com/2009/05/28/jquery-fadeinfadeout-ie-cleartype-glitch/.

To preserve the information in StackOverflow, here are the contents of that link:

> Thanks to Benjamin Michael Novakovic
>   for this fix!
>
> jQuery fadeIn/fadeOut IE cleartype glitch
>
> While using the jQuery  javascript library today at work, I noticed a
>   glitch under IE7. When fading a html
>   node with the .fadeIn() and .fadeOut()
>   functions in jQuery, IE drops the
>   windows Cleartype rendering; which
>   results in very ugly text. This
>   problem appears to be very common, but
>   no one has a nice solution for the
>   problem.
>
> The most common way to solve this problem is by removing the filter CSS
>   attribute. In normal javascript, it
>   would look like this:
>
> ```
> document.getElementById('node').style.removeAttribute('filter');
> ```
>
> and in jQuery, it would look like this:
>
> ```
> $('#node').fadeOut('slow', function() {
>    this.style.removeAttribute('filter');
> });
> ```
>
> via Benjamin Michael Novakovic »
>   jQuery fadeIn/fadeOut IE cleartype
>   glitch.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Add this on top of your html documents. It works on IE 8.07xxxx. I'm not sure this technique works on IE 7.

Answer (score 1):

Add this into your JS. It fixes the bug and maintains the correct scope. When added to jQuery, it still passes all unit tests:

```
(function($){
    $.each(['fadeIn', 'fadeOut'], function(i, method){
        var _fn = $.fn[method];
        $.fn[method] = function(easing, callbackå, cancel) {
            if ($.isFunction(easing)) {
                callback = easing;
                easing = 'normal';
            }
            return _fn.call(this, easing, function(){
                jQuery.browser.msie && !cancel && this.style.removeAttribute('filter');
                (callback || $.noop).call(this);
            });
        }
    })
})(jQuery);
```

Written by me :)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I got rid of my ugly faded in text on IE 8: use `fadeTo` instead and gear it up to 99%!

Therefore this worked for me:

```
$(function() {
   $('p.quote').fadeTo("slow",0.99);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked for me fading in a div using jQuery's animate, as the filter was in the style element. Therefore is what I needed to do:

```
$(div).animate({opacity: 1}, 800, function() {
   $(this).removeAttr('style');
});
```

Obviously this will remove any other inline styles you may have too.

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked for me either or else they were unsuitable, for example I don't want to change my HTML5 DTD declaration just for one IE bug, and I can't change my background color as its being used in another animation.

I'm also using jQuery `.animate` so this may be a little off topic but the solution that worked perfectly was [this one](http://coilmedia.com/post/2010/jquery-text-loses-antialiasing-when-animating-css-opacity-in-internet-explorer/). Its a good article but the core code is:

```
$('#sample').animate(
    {opacity:1.0},
    500,
    function() {
        $(this).css('filter','');
    }
);
```