# Distortion of text in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, apache-shindig

Im using shinding engine , and whenever I move one gadget for repositioning, the bold text inside that gadget gets distorted.

1. [image: Before Moving gadget]
2. [image: After moving gadget]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE has an issue where it stops using anti-aliasing once parts of the DOM are modified. There are some work-arounds (Google for these). I think IE9 fixes the problem.

See this question:
[jQuery fadeIn leaves text not anti-aliased in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778208/jquery-fadein-leaves-text-not-anti-aliased-in-ie7)

Some links in that seem dead.

One of these two changes might help (you may have to experiment with which element to apply them to):

```
myElement.style.filter = '';
```

or

```
$(myElement).removeAttr('style');
```

Other info:
http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/haslayout
http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/filter

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer gets rid of Anti-Aliasing temporarily when performing such tasks as jQuery fade and the example you gave!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **custom fadeIn/fadeOut/fadeTo** to solve your problem

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.customFadeIn = function(speed, callback) {
        $(this).fadeIn(speed, function() {
            if(!$.support.opacity)
                $(this).get(0).style.removeAttribute('filter');
            if(callback != undefined)
                callback();
        });
    };
    $.fn.customFadeOut = function(speed, callback) {
        $(this).fadeOut(speed, function() {
            if(!$.support.opacity)
                $(this).get(0).style.removeAttribute('filter');
            if(callback != undefined)
                callback();
        });
    };
    $.fn.customFadeTo = function(speed,to,callback) {
        return this.animate({opacity: to}, speed, function() {
            if (to == 1 && jQuery.browser.msie)
                this.style.removeAttribute('filter');
            if (jQuery.isFunction(callback))
                callback();
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```