# jQuery opacity problem in ie

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, text, opacity

I am getting this wired aliased text and image borders in IE only which you can see in image.

[image]

As you can see in javascript i am using jQuery and css(opacity).

This is my html:

```
<div id="banner-container">
    <div id="banner-0" class="banner">
        <div class="banner-text">
            <div class="banner-text-heading-3">0 Lorem ipsum dolor si</div>
            <div class="banner-text-text-3">0 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea <br /><b>Learn more</b></div>
        </div>
        <div class="banner-image"><img src="images/banner-img.png" border="0" /></div>
    </div>
    <div id="banner-1" class="banner">
        <div class="banner-text">
            <div class="banner-text-heading-3">1 Lorem ipsum dolor si</div>
            <div class="banner-text-text-3">1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea <br /><b>Learn more</b></div>
        </div>
        <div class="banner-image"><img src="images/banner-img1.png" border="0" /></div>
    </div>
    <div id="banner-2" class="banner">
        <div class="banner-text">
            <div class="banner-text-heading-3">2 Lorem ipsum dolor si</div>
            <div class="banner-text-text-3">2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea <br /><b>Learn more</b></div>
        </div>
        <div class="banner-image"><img src="images/banner-img2.png" border="0" /></div>
    </div>   
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    slide_logic(0,3,0);
});
function slide_logic(slide,nof_slides,animation_duration)
{
    for(i=0;i<nof_slides;i++)
    {
        if(i==slide)
        {
            $('#banner-'+i).animate({'opacity':'1'},animation_duration);
            $('#banner-'+i+' .banner-text').animate({'opacity':'1'},animation_duration);
        }
        else
        {
            $('#banner-'+i).animate({'opacity':'0'},animation_duration);
            $('#banner-'+i+' .banner-text').animate({'opacity':'0'},animation_duration);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any fix for that?

Comment: I've had this issue before - do you have any background color set for IE?

Comment: Support for opacity in IE8 and earlier is very poor. There's no getting away from this fact; it is buggy and badly implemented. JQuery might make it easier to use, but it can't fix the bugs.

Comment: @SolMan, No background color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the answers here: [jQuery fadeIn leaves text not anti-aliased in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778208/jquery-fadein-leaves-text-not-anti-aliased-in-ie7)

May be it will help. Appears that it may be bug of IE (as usual)

Comment: +1, Thanks for your response. I have added following code in callback of animate if($.browser.msie) this.style.removeAttribute('filter'); it fixes the issue when not animating but same issue when animating.